# GTMSessionFetcherService linker error when trying to build my xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm using Cocoapods to install the latest GPG and used the latest XCode 7.3 and iOS SDK 9.3 but I couldn't manage to make the build of my project and stuck with these 5 linker error which I couldn't solve :

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GIPNetworkImage.o)
   objc-class-ref in libSignIn_external.a(GIDSignIn.o)

  "_GSDK_kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn authCodeObtained] in libGTMOAuth2_external_external.a(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherAssertValidSelector", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2Authentication authorizeRequest:delegate:didFinishSelector:] in libGTMOAuth2_external_external.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn initWithAuthentication:authorizationURL:delegate:webRequestSelector:finishedSelector:] in libGTMOAuth2_external_external.a(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGTMOAuth2_internal_external.a(GTMOAuth2SignInInternal.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGTMOAuth2_external_external.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGTMOAuth2_external_external.a(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGClearcutLogger.o)
      objc-class-ref in libSignIn_external.a(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in libSignIn_external.a(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've even tried to add GTMSessionFetcherService source in my project but can't seem to fix this. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem...what fixed for me adding the GoogleSignIn.framework and GoogleSignIn.bundle

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a very similar build issue while trying to integrate Google Sign-In. The [non-Cocoapods instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/#add_the_sdk_your_xcode_project) mention adding `GoogleSignIn.framework` to your project, but they don't tell you that you need to link the rest of the frameworks in the sign-in SDK as well:

```
GoogleAppUtilities.framework
GoogleAuthUtilities.framework
GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
GoogleSignIn.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework
```

Comment: Not only that they specifically asked you to only add SignIn framework, Bundle and nothing else :|

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is **add** `GoogleOpenSource.framework` from the **[Google+ iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1.zip)** to **libs**

then

**add** GoogleOpenSource to your `robovm.xml`

Finally make sure the **GoogleSignIn robopod** is present

Comment: I added the googleOpenSource.framework but I'm not sure how to add robovm.xml since that file doesn't exist in my project.
Still facing the same linker problem.. which is weird since I've been scouring the internet for the last few days and it seems no one have the same problem as I do

Comment: yes I did.. I used cocoapods to get the latest whatever build google has

Answer (score 0):

Add libsqlite3.dylib, libz.tbd, and AddressBook.framework to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". This solved my issue.Also I copied these frameworks too.

```
GoogleAppUtilities.framework
GoogleAuthUtilities.framework
GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
GoogleSignIn.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue for Xamarin.iOS.
To solve, I simply updated my Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn package to the latest version (4.0.1.1) and updated Xamarin.Build.Download to latests (0.4.2).

Updating these two packages caused extra packages to be added to my project.  I believe it's these extra packages that fixed the native linker errors I was getting (same exact errors as Yanuar Tanil).